# is there a better way to ask this question or a better place

Tags: support

I asked this question https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/81466/does-google-resell-what-you-search-for-to-third-party-information-providers and am curious if there is a better place or way to ask this. I fully understand it's a bit of a difficult thing to answer - was hoping to find someone who had insight here but would understand if not.

I disagree a bit with the comments but everybody has an opinion.

Comment: It's not a security question at all, so no one should answer it here. You could try asking Google.

Comment: It is not even a data privacy question as per the scope of the site

Comment: thx for your opinion

Comment: From what I know, Google sells information about people's online behaviour in demographics. i.e. Age: 18-24 and Gender: Male (https://www.thinkwithgoogle.com/products/demographics.html) They don't specifically sell data about individual users, although it may be possible to deanonymize an individual from the data. (https://cyberlaw.stanford.edu/blog/2011/07/there-no-such-thing-anonymous-online-tracking) Unfortunatly the answer to the question asked here is no. Try asking in the DMZ.

Comment: talked to a friend whois an information security lawyer; basically, he said that Google's deanonymized data is pretty trivial to break and that it is both in demographics and individual user level. He said most serious data vendors have individual deals with google that go from extremely inane to quite sophisticated.

Comment: thx josh - I appreciate your answer. I find the down-voting and deleting of my question a bit disappointing.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, this question revolved around Google's security and privacy policy.

This is not a subject anyone in here can give a proper answer to. It would require a thorough search in Google terms of service agreement as well as commercial contracts which are not usually public. And even then, we cannot assume what would be in the data send from Google to a company (thus this is opinion-based).

If someone here was to have 'insight' on what's really going on, he would probably be unable to answer you because of confidentiality agreements.

The question could be on-topic if there were a public document stating exactly what Google is doing with their data (no more opinion based), and even then I would close this question as it would be trivial to find the answer on Google's website.

Comment: of course, somebody could give an answer without the confidentiality issues you mentioned. For example, "yes I know of two companies where they sync search phrases specifically about medical conditions (for example) with end uesrs and provide to health providers". In the US (at least), there's no breaching of confidentiality agreements.

Answer (score 2):

The question was closed by the community as while data privacy is very much on topic, this doesn't automatically make every question about data privacy on topic.

As M'vy pointed out on your original question, and here, you are just asking about google's business practices, not a security question as per our site scope.

Don't take the voting to close and deletion personally. The question just doesn't work here.